# Setting a C# variable to the value of an auto-incremented column value in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Alright, so I have a project I'm doing that simulates a parking garage ticket machine. I have to be able to let the user clock in, assign them a ticket, and let them use that ticket to clock out and charge them based on time in the parking garage. I am inserting their data into a table that has an auto incremented ID column because I need to be able to track which ticket they are and add/remove them accordingly. I am running this code to add their ticket to the database and it runs fine, I am running into some trouble taking the ID that the database gives their ticket and assigning that to the Ticket object the assignment wants us to use. Here is the code I am using when they clock in.

```
    private void EnterBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DateTime timeIn = new DateTime();
        timeIn = DateTime.Now;
        int ticketID = 0;

        MessageBox.Show("Entered Parking Garage at: " + timeIn.ToString());

        //Insert Data into the table, increment the ticketID, store that as the TicketNumber 
        //in the ticket object
        string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Tickets (TimeIssued)";
        sqlQuery += "VALUES (@TimeIssued)";
        using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=stusql.otc.edu;Initial Catalog=th0732193;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand dataCommand = dataConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                dataConnection.Open();
                dataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                dataCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIssued", timeIn);
                dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                ticketID = Convert.ToInt32(dataCommand.Parameters["@TicketID"].Value.ToString());
                dataConnection.Close();

            }
        }

        Ticket newTicket = new Ticket();
        newTicket.TimeIn = timeIn;
        newTicket.TicketNumber = ticketID;
    }
```

So the main problem is that since the column is auto incremented, I can't add a parameter or it will mess that up (unless there is a way of doing it that I don't know about, which if so, great!), and that's a problem because I need to assign that ticketID to the ticket object.

My question is, how can I set that TicketID that is stored in the database to the Ticker number property in my Ticket object.

I've looked all over and cannot find a solution to this problem that will help me in my specific case, so although I'm sure this is a dumb question, I really need some help, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/ - You *should* be able to append the select to your query, and grab the result via `Execute` (forgot exact name) instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: @Rob: most likely `.ExecuteScalar()` since that `SELECT` will return exactly one row, one column only (the newly inserted `ID`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change sql query as below

```
string sqlQuery ="INSERT INTO Tickets (TimeIssued) OUTPUT INSERTED.TicketID VALUES(@TimeIssued)
```

then

```
dataCommand.CommandText = sqlQuery;
dataCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeIssued", timeIn);
 int TicketID = (int) dataCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work, adding it after the dataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery line?

```
dataCommand.CommandText = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
int id = dataCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: Be careful with this - if the application is threaded, it's possible a different row is inserted at the same time, so both threads would grab the same identity.

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)